# Generic parameter 'Parent' could not be inferred

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm working on my first Swift/SwiftUI project (other than the tutorials) and have run into what I think is a common problem -- the error `Generic parameter 'Parent' could not be inferred` -- toward the top of the view when the problem is actually with a `List` I'm trying to generate lower down in the form.

The app I'm building is a simple invoicing app: the user fills out the form fields and sends the invoice. An invoice can have multiple line items that the user enters one at a time and then are appended to a dictionary that *should* display inside the form.

This is the relevant variables from the top of the struct and the beginning of the view, where I hope I'm declaring the variables for line items correctly to modify them based on user input.

*Edited following @asperi's advice below.

```
@State private var lineItems = [LineItem]()
@State private var lineItem = LineItem()

struct LineItem: Codable, Hashable {

    var productSku: String = ""
    var productName: String = ""
    var quantity: Double = 0
    var unitPrice: Double = 0
}

func addLineItem(lineItem: LineItem){
    lineItems.append(lineItem)
}
...   
var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
          Form {
            Section(header: Text("Customer Information")) { <-- error appears here
              TextField("Customer Name", text: $customerName)
              TextField("Customer Email", text: $customerEmail)
          }
```

Here's the relevant portion of the form, where I'm trying to list all current line items and then allow the user to insert additional line items. I don't get any error until I add the `List` code, so I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong there.

```
Section(header: Text("Items")) {
    List(lineItems, id: \.self) { item in
        LineItemRow(lineItem: item)
        Text(item.productName)
    }
    TextField("Product SKU", text: $productSKU)
    TextField("Poduct Name", text: $productName)
    TextField("Unit Price", text: $unitPrice, formatter: DoubleFormatter())
    Picker("Quantity", selection: $quantity) {
        ForEach(0 ..< 10) {
            Text("\($0)")
        }
    }
    Button(action: {
        self.addLineItem(lineItem: LineItem(productSku:$productSKU,
                                            productName:$productName,
                                            quantity:$unitPrice,
                                            unitPrice:$quantity))
        print($lineItems)
    }, label: {
        Text("Add line item")
    })

}
```

I've tested the button functionality in the console and it does seem to be appending to the dictionary correctly, but I need it to display as well.

I'm probably getting something very basic wrong with the `List`. Any advice?

For reference, here's the whole view:

```
struct AddInvoiceForm: View {
    @State private var invoiceNumber: String = ""
    @State private var _description: String = ""
    @State private var dueDate: Date = Date()
    @State private var sendImmediately: Bool = true

    @State private var currency = 0
    @State private var paymentType = 0

    @State private var customerName: String = ""
    @State private var customerEmail: String = ""

    @State private var productSKU: String = ""
    @State private var productName: String = ""
    @State private var quantity: Int = 0
    @State private var unitPrice: String = ""

    @State private var lineItems = [LineItem]()
    @State private var lineItem = LineItem()

    struct LineItem: Codable, Hashable {

        var productSku: String = ""
        var productName: String = ""
        var quantity: Double = 0
        var unitPrice: Double = 0
    }

    func addLineItem(lineItem: LineItem){
        lineItems.append(lineItem)
    }

    @State private var totalAmount: Double = 0.0

    static let currencies = ["USD","GBP"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("Customer Information")) {
                    TextField("Customer Name", text: $customerName)
                    TextField("Customer Email", text: $customerEmail)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Invoice Information")) {
                    TextField("Invoice Number", text:$invoiceNumber)
                    TextField("Description", text:$_description)
                    DatePicker(selection: $dueDate, in: Date()..., displayedComponents: .date) {
                        Text("Due date")
                    }
                    Picker("Currency", selection: $currency) {
                       ForEach(0 ..< Self.currencies.count) {
                           Text(Self.currencies[$0])
                       }
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Items")) {
                    List(lineItems, id: \.self) { item in
                        LineItemRow(lineItem: item)
                        Text(item.productName)
                    }
                    TextField("Product SKU", text: $productSKU)
                    TextField("Poduct Name", text: $productName)
                    TextField("Unit Price", text: $unitPrice, formatter: DoubleFormatter())
                    Picker("Quantity", selection: $quantity) {
                        ForEach(0 ..< 10) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                        }
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        self.addLineItem(lineItem: LineItem(productSku:$productSKU,
                                                            productName:$productName,
                                                            quantity:$unitPrice,
                                                            unitPrice:$quantity))
                        print($lineItems)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Add line item")
                    })

                }
                Section(header: Text("Totals")) {
                    Text("\(totalAmount)")
                }
                Section {
                    Button(action: {
                        print(Text("Send"))
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Send invoice")
                    })
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle("Invoice Details")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it with the Xcode 11.4 beta? The error messages are better.

Comment: I haven't it. I'll try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> List(lineItems, id: \.productSku) { item in <-- I get the error when I add this
> ```

Your item is dictionary, but dictionary does not have `.productSku` key path, so the error.

I assume most simple & correct would be to make `Item` as struct

```
struct LineItem {
   var productSku: String
   ...
}

...

@State private var lineItems = [LineItem]()
@State private var lineItem = LineItem()

...

List(lineItems, id: \.productSku) { item in
```

Comment: This is a great idea, but I end up with the same error if I refactor LineItem as a struct. Also, if I try to declare `@State private var lineItem = LineItem()` I get an additional error that I can't invoke it with no arguments.

Comment: @tchaymore, sure, I don't have all your code, so the idea is scratchy... but it will allow you to avoid many other pitfalls and errors with dictionary. Put default values for properties in LineItem so default constructor works.

Comment: Oh man, stupid of me to miss default values. I just updated my question to follow your advice and dropped in the whole view code at the end.

Comment: I'm going to mark yours as correct because, like you said, it led me to the right place. In addition to a really stupid typo, there was an issue with the subview I was trying to use and I think that is what was really throwing the error inside of `List`. Thanks!